# Running PHP Script In Powershell keeps opening NotePad ++ rather than executing the PHP script

Tags: php, powershell

Okay, I'm at a bit of a loss here.

I'm testing out running PHP scripts from within powershell and it just keeps opening NotePad ++ rather than executing the script. I cannot figure out why this won't work...

I'm using a pretty basic PHP script to test:

```
<?php
    echo 'Hello, World!';
?>
```

And I'm calling it using the standard way I run .ps1 files:

```
PS C:\php> c:\phpfiles\test25.php
```

The execution policy is set to unrestricted... what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're just launching the file with its default editor, which happens to be Notepat++ on your machine. If you want to run php, you have to call php and pass it the file. `php -f 
 c:\phpfiles\test25.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass the path of the file as an argument to the PHP executable. If (lets say) PHP is installed in c:\php, then you must do:

```
PS c:\php\php.exe -f c:\phpfiles\test25.php
```